# Почему пакет для MS Store не подгружает .pdb для логирования stack trace?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, microsoft-store

Я в проекте использую свою dll и boost для stack trace. Если обернуть мое приложения в пакет, то перестают подгружаться (или еще чего) .pdb лежащие рядом с dll и .exe для нормального stack trace с именами функций и тд. Однако, если вручную зайти в папку приложения AppX (если развернули для дебага в VS) и запустить .exe то все работает как надо. Такое чувство что стоит какое-то ограничение для использования .pdb из под пакета.

К тому-же по умолчанию .pdb не копируются в папку с исполняемыми модулями, это можно сделать установив `<AppxPackageIncludePrivateSymbols>true</AppxPackageIncludePrivateSymbols>` в .wapproj .

В самой dll через /PDBALTPATH установлен относительный путь поиска .pdb в той же папке что и dll. Так что проблема не в этом.

Comment: Учитывая, что dbghelp.h вроде как в UWP не доступен, это не удивительно. Кроме того, непонятна ситуация, когда она может понадобиться в UWP приложении без отладчика.